# What are problems at the center of geometric topology of 2 dimensions?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, advice

I am working on Geometric Topology in 2 dimensions but I don't know which problems are important and make many connections between different areas. I hope Mathematicians can give me some ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps you could add more context. What is your background? If you are working on a project or thesis at a university work, why can't you ask  your adviser to suggest a problem?

Comment: This is way too vague.  I've voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Table of Contents of this book might help focus your question,
e.g., one chapter is on "The Schönflies theorem."

> Moise, Edwin E. *Geometric topology in dimensions 2 and 3*. Vol. 47. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.
>   ([Springer link](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461299080).)
>
> ---
>
> [image: Cover]

---